# Angular.js gives maximum call stack size error when using d3.layout.partition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

i have created a angularjs directive which creates a d3 sunburst chart. The problem is I keep getting maximum call stack error in chrome and too much recursion error in firefox. I have tracked the problem to the function d3.layout.partition. Now this is a function provided by d3.js to plug in values to create a sunburst chart or any hierarchical chart. I currently have no idea how to fix this problem. Any  suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

chrome error

[image]

firefox error

[image]

```
      var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .children(function(d){ return d.values; })
        .value(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.count; });            

      var root = d3.nest()
            .key(function(k){ return k.key})
            .entries(d);

      root = {key:'All',values:root};

      console.log(partition.nodes(root))
```

the partition.nodes(root) results in the recursion error

Comment: Perhaps a simple [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will explain it better.

Comment: I have edited the question with a screenshot and code snippet

Comment: I suspect digestTtl could be the reason, which is by default set to 10.
please have a [look](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider)

Comment: I tried setting digestTtl to a high number. didnt work

Comment: can you prepare whole setup on fiddle or somewhere, where i can have a look.

Comment: are you using a scope.watch in your code? I'm suspecting that you are watching binded data that is also handled by d3. Everytime d3 changes the data digest sense it and initial a cycle. Change the watch/ or remove the watch after the first change should be fine

Comment: @user2289175 Could you suggest how to change the watch or remove it after the first change? I'm running into a similar problem with D3/Angular and trying to figure out how to implement what you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisCasad look at my provided answer. Cheers

Comment: @biobirdman actually my question was meant for you I just reference the wrong user. =) I understand in theory what you're saying I'm just having a hard time determining how I would implement your suggestions. I tried adding a conditional inside of the watch so that it wouldn't do anything after a variable is set the first time, but it seems just the fact that the watch is called is more the problem then what's inside the watch?

Comment: @Chris Casad In your watch, you will have a call the function that will plot the your chart.

Comment: @biobirdman I do in fact have a function call in my watch. I've recreated the issue within a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ccasad/edqqrt3x/  When you run it you get "Maximum call stack size exceeded". This was inspired from the following article: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Comment: @biobirdman When you said "look at my provided answer" I thought you were talking about your comment. I didn't realize you had posted it as an answer to this post. Sorry about that. I'm looking into your answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I cant really tell what is the cause of your problem (since your did not show enough code), I use to have this problem but I managed to solve this problem by.

1. Place your d3 code into the controller instead of the directive
2. If you decide to have your d3 code in the directive, remove the watcher after the first watch. To do this you may, taken from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm

   ```
               var unbindWatcher = $scope.$watch(
                   "clickCount",
                   function( newClickCount ) {
                       console.log( "Watching click count." );
                       if ( newClickCount >= 5 ) {
                           $scope.isShowingFeedback = true;
                           unbindWatcher(); }
                          }
                     });
   ```

Reasons :

While there are a number of tutorial that shows placing your d3 code into the directive (since they manipulate the DOM), I personally feels that it might be more appropriate place to have d3 code in the controller, as I still rely heavily on d3 and not angularjs to manipulate the DOM. Of course, I cant be 100% certain, since I only start using AngularJS not long ago.